# Is it possible to obtain time from a WiFi access point without connecting to it?

Tags: android, datetime, wifi

I'm working on an android based device without telephony hardware. It would be nice to automatically set up time when user boots it up for the first time. Is it possible to get a timestamp via WiFi access point scanning without actually connecting to any access point?

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't possible.  There is no requirement that a WiFi access point broadcast it's timestamp, nor that it has an accurate clock at all.

If your device has GPS, you can get it from that, but not from WiFi.